# Can't open PDF files in Electron

Tags: javascript, node.js, pdf, electron, chromium

I followed the suggestions in the answers of related questions, i.e. specifying

```
webPreferences: {
      plugins: true
}
```

as part of the options when creating the BrowserWindow instance, but it is simply not working. Whenever I try to load/open/view a PDF file in electron, all I get is what looks like an empty/broken chromium PDF viewer like on this screenshot:

[image]

My electron version is "^13.1.2" according to my `package.json` and this is my `main.js`

```
// main.js

// Modules to control application life and create native browser window
const { app, BrowserWindow } = require('electron')
const path = require('path')

function createWindow () {
  // Create the browser window.
  const win = new BrowserWindow({
    width: 800,
    height: 600,
    webPreferences: {
      plugins: true
    }
  });

  // and load the index.html of the app.
  win.loadFile('test.pdf');
}

app.whenReady().then(() => {
  createWindow()
})

app.on('window-all-closed', function () {
      app.quit()
})
```

Can anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Last time I checked, Electron doesn't support opening `pdf` files natively anymore

Comment: I believe pdf viewer is enabled now, but there are some bugs in the later version where it doesn't work. You could try downgrading

Answer (score 1):

An upgrade of electron helped me. i switched from 13.x to 16.x and it works now

Answer (score 0):

> Use PDFWindow package

`//main.js

app.on('ready', () => {
const win = new PDFWindow({
width: 800,
height: 600
})

win.loadURL('test.pdf')
})

//package.json

"dependencies": {
"electron-pdf-window": "^1.0.12",
},

> 

`

Comment: Thanks but I'd rather not introduce a dependency on some 3rd-party package for functionality that should be included in the framework.